# NUnit data driven unit test with datasource

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, nunit, test-data

I have one data source like -4,-3,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,2,3,4 , I have one function and this function can capture repeated number for example in this data source we have -3,2 are repeated .The repeated numbers are reported in end of the program.
I couldn't find good example(I spent 3 hours).
How can I implement a unit test with NUnit that can be test the same situation and it tells me the results, if you have some example , It will be very useful to me.(Really appreciated).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `TestCase` attributes for simple data like what you've described.

```
[Test]
[TestCase(new[] { -4, -3, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4 }, new []{-3,2})]
public void YourTest(int[] given, int[] expected)    
{  ... }
```

Note:  ReSharper (at least my version of it) doesn't honor multiple test cases like this one so I had to confirm multiple test cases with the NUnit GUI.

Comment: +1 I think Test is optional if you mark the method with TestCase

Comment: Thanks, Can we show the first index of array for any repeat-at.for example -3-->1 and 2-->7

Comment: @user1824702:  What's the scope of this question?

Comment: @user1824702:  I'm not entirely following that, which is probably why you're struggling to write a unit test for it.  Unit test the parts and the whole will eventually be obvious.

Answer (score 2):

First things first - get a working test. Something like this:

```
    [Test]
    public void DetectsMinusThreeAndTwo()
    {
        RepeatingDigitsDetector target = new RepeatingDigitsDetector();
        int[] source = new int[] { -4, -3, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4 };
        int[] expected = new int[] { -3, -2 };
        int[] actual = target.GetRepeats(source);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.Length, actual.Length, "checking lengths");
        for (int i = 0; i < expected.Length; i++)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(expected[i], actual[i], "checking element {0}", i);
        }
    }
```

Later, you can start adding in goodies like the `TestCase` or `TestCaseSource` attributes. But if you're trying to do TDD (as the [tdd](/questions/tagged/tdd) tag implies), you need to start with **a** test.

Comment: Thank you @Edmund, I would like we have external data source like Excel, Access,.. , such as MSTest

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [TestCaseSource](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5) in this instance. Several tests could make the data harder to read inside the TestCase attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As your test data gets complex, it will be difficult to handle.
Consider storing your data in another source such as excel, json or Database.

I personally like storing test data in embedded json files.
The package [JsonSectionReader](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WonderTools.JsonSectionReader/) provides good support for this.